# Debug logs to identify UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW error

Tags: apex, debugging

I am seeing the following error across my entire organization:

```
UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW
```

Every process builder, flow, etc. is erroring out into this lock error. How can I leverage the debug logs to identify processes(s) that may be contributing to this error.

Comment: If it is easy to reproduce then open the Salesforce dev console and perform an interaction with your Salesforce org as the same user where you see this error. You should see debug log entries listed in the Logs tab of the dev console and with luck one or more will show there was a problem. Open the log and search/filter to show database operations. You should be able to find the DML or SOQL causing the issue that way.

Comment: If you have extreme data skew or every record looking up to a very small number of parents, that's a good first place to focus with the strategy Phil articulated.

Comment: @PhilW Do you have additional resources for identifying the problematic DML or SOQL. I am struggling to put this into action.

Comment: Start here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_system_log.htm&type=5